# How to make a range dashed in tikz-timing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-timing

I draw a timing diagram with `TikZ-timing`. The overall timing is too long. Therefore the diagram shows the start and the end of the signal timing. This shall be illustrated with dashed lines in all lines of

- Bus
- Access counter
- Idle bus bit-period counter

The dashed lines should be in the range from x=4,8 up to x=5.8. The lowest signal is shown steeper here.

How can I make all horizontal lines dashed for the corresponding range?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %[node a/.style={ font=\tiny}]
        %\draw (0,0)  node[a]{Counter};
        \node at (0,0.0) [font=\tiny] {Counter};
        \node at (0,0.2) [font=\tiny] {Bit-period};
        \node at (0,0.4) [font=\tiny] {Idle Bus};

        \node at (0,3.2) [font=\tiny]{Access-};
        \node at (0,3.0) [font=\tiny]{counter};
        \node at (0,3.6) [font=\tiny]{Bus};
        \node at (0,4.0) [font=\tiny]{Action};
        
        % Action
        \draw[<->] (2.5,4) -- (7.3,4);
        \draw (2.5,4.1) -- (2.5,3.9);
        \draw (7.3,4.1) -- (7.3,3.9);
        \draw (6.5,4.1) -- (6.5,3.9);
        \node at (4.8,4.1) [font=\tiny]{Idle bus};
        \node at (6.9,4.1) [font=\tiny]{Sync};      
        % Bus
        \timing(1,3.5) {3U20H3U3H};
        % Accesscounter
        \timing(1,3) {5D X 2D{1} 2D{2} 2D{3} 2D{4} 8D{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~3} D{4} 6D{1} };
        % Idle bus bit-period counter
        \timing(1,0) {LLL!{ -- +(12,4.3) -- +(17,9.5) -- +(19,10) -- +(19,0)
                 -- +(23,0) -- +(26,2) } };
        % Bit-perion counter values
        \draw (2.8,0.50) node [font=\tiny]{40};
        \draw (3.2,0.65) node [font=\tiny]{50};
        \draw (3.6,0.80) node [font=\tiny]{60};
        \draw (4.0,0.95) node [font=\tiny]{70};
        \draw (4.4,1.10) node [font=\tiny]{80};
        \draw (6.2,2.50) node [font=\tiny]{360};

        % left and right border     
        \draw (1,-0.2) -- (1,4.2);
        \draw (8,-0.2) -- (8,4.2);

%       \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (10,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Current result:

[image]

The desired result should be similar to this:
[image]